# Kubernetes kubectl command to lookup Key in configMap or Secrets

Tags: kubernetes

I have about 10 ConfigMap and few secrets which stores my configuration in key and value. I am looking for any kubectl command which i can use to find my key in any available configMap or secrets ?
I know I can open each file and find my key but is there any `kubectl` command which lookup all configMap or Serects to find my key?

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/

Answer (score 2):

Create the following kubectl plugin

```
#!/bin/bash

kubectl get secrets -o go-template='{{range $s:=.items}}{{range $k,$v:=$s.data}}{{printf "Secret %s: %s\n" $s.metadata.name $k}}{{end}}{{end}}' | grep -i $1
kubectl get configmap -o go-template='{{range $s:=.items}}{{range $k,$v:=$s.data}}{{printf "CM %s: %s\n" $s.metadata.name $k}}{{end}}{{end}}' | grep -i $1
```

It will have to be located somewhere on your execution path and be executable

```
# Make script executable
chmod +x /home/mark/bin/kubectl-find-key

# Check it can be found
kubectl plugin list
```

Lastly it can be used as follows

```
$ kubectl find key database
CM myapp-details: DATABASE_HOSTNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be not the best solution but it works, at the moment it's the only way comes to my mind. If I will find different solution, I will edit this answer.

If your `kubectl` command will only specify `resource` without specific name it will print information from all objects of that specified resource. `kubectl describe cm` will print description of all `ConfigMaps`

For test I've created 5 [ConfigMaps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) from [documentation example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) (with data.game.properties and data.ui.properties). In 3 of them I've set the same key `test` with value `1`,`3` or `5`.

```
$ kubectl get cm
NAME   DATA   AGE
cm1    1      20m
cm2    1      21m
cm3    1      21m
cm4    1      21m
cm5    1      21m
```

So easiest way is to just use `kubest get cm -o yaml` which will print all `ConfigMaps` in YAML format and then `grep` them by key or value.

```
$ kubectl get cm -o yaml | grep test
      test=configmap1
        {"apiVersion":"v1","data":{"game.properties":"enemies=aliens\nlives=3\ntest=configmap1\n"},"kind":"ConfigMap","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"cm1","namespace":"default"}}
      test=configmap3
        {"apiVersion":"v1","data":{"game.properties":"secret.code.allowed=true\nsecret.code.lives=30\ntest=configmap3\n"},"kind":"ConfigMap","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"cm3","namespace":"default"}}
      test=configmap5
        {"apiVersion":"v1","data":{"ui.properties":"allow.textmode=true\nhow.nice.to.look=fairlyNice \ntest=configmap5\n"},"kind":"ConfigMap","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"cm5","namespace":"default"}}
```

So `cm1` include `test=configmap1`, `cm3` include `test=configmap3` and `cm5` include `test=configmap5`. Instead of `YAML` you can also use `JSON`.

In addition, as `ConfigMap` is `namespaced` you can use `-A` flag to check all `namespaces`.

```
$ kubectl get cm -o yaml -A | grep test
```

It might be hard to read, but in console output it will be highlighted.

You can do the same with [Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/).

Answer (score 0):

How about using this command since there are 4 sequential hyphens after the keys when describe the configmap

```
$ kubectl describe configmap myconfig | grep -B1 "\-\-\-\-"
key1:
----
--
key2:
----
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).